# iOS App Tap Status Bar Scroll

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Generally in iOS apps, tapping the status bar (clock) scrolls to the very top. In the SE app it scrolls to the top of the content, but does not include the search bar. You still need to drag further to reveal that.

This inconsistency may lead users to miss the fact of the search bar's existence in the first place.

This is on the main site page, where you could for instance search a tag or change sorting.

Comment: Thanks for the report, this is a good point. I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, most iOS apps, especially Apple's apps, do follow this beahvior.

This has been fixed for for question listing and will look like this when you tap on the status bar:

[image: scroll to top]

**This fix will be available in 0.1.17.**

Comment: Any ETA when 0.1.17 will be released? Quite a few bugs fixed already. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard it was released a few minutes ago

Comment: Cool, reinstalled and confirmed bug fixes. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out this was in Feed as well. But you caught it there too :)