# Tap Menu Bar to scroll up in Questions/Answer view

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, menu-bar

I see that this behavior was [implemented for the feed view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221477/ios-app-tap-status-bar-scroll), but I'd like to be able to tap the menu bar to scroll up in the Question & Answer views as well. It's honestly where I find myself scrolling up more anyway.

Comment: Gah!!! Why won't my fixes ever stick?!?

Comment: @brian, testing it out some more tonight and it seems to be working now. Not sure. Might just be user error.

Comment: It happens intermittently when there are code blocks in the HTML. It's a bit tricky to solve.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is working again.  iOS bug?  Anyone's guess.

Comment: Working here too. Was definitely broken at the time this question was posted